# LDAP Login when email address and userPrincipalName is different

Tags: ldap, openldap

Hi i am trying to log users in with ldap.

Is it possible to log users in with their email addresses even if the email address is different than userPrincipalName?

It works when combining username@domain and log users in through LDAP with the userPrincipalName.

So I also change the search settings when user uses an email that is not same as its userPrincipalName as follows:

```
LDAP.bindValue = function (usernameOrEmail, isEmailAddress, FQDN) {
 //FQDN is the domain name as example.com
LDAP.searchField = ((isEmailAddress) ? 'mail' : 'userPrincipalName');
 LDAP.searchValueType = ((isEmailAddress) ? 'mail' : 'userPrincipalName'); 
 return ((isEmailAddress) ? usernameOrEmail : usernameOrEmail + '@' + FQDN)
}
```

What would be the query to search users by email?

Thanks

Comment: I understand I'm really late to this party, but... if it's still an issue, what application is this supposed to be used to log into?  I mean, the answer to your general question is "Yes", but once you clarify to logging into a particular thing, that becomes more uncertain - but much more possible to explain how if it can be done.  I would assume that you're probably asking about logging into a computer itself, but even at that, what operating system you're talking about has a significant impact.  If it is logging into the computer itself, the OS should probably be a question tag.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that the application logs in as itself, an admin user with search privileges, searches for the user using some unique attribute such as email, and then tries to bind as that user using the found DN and the password supplied.

Comment: I think i wasn't cleare with my question. I can do the login. But it only works with users who have same userPrincipalName and email. In my case I have a user who does not match these criteria. Therefore I am looking for a way to search mail of the user but it is not working.

Comment: 'It is not working' is not a problem description. If your question is really about how to search for a user by his email address, that is what it should state. It doesn't.

Comment: you are right @EJP, sorry for being vague. What I meant was how do I search users by email. I have edited the question as well. thanks.